# Facebook iOS SDK not returning email after changing app name

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-login

I have integrated Facebook login using FBLoginView. The response that i get in the delegate method (loginViewFetchedUserInfo) does not include the email of the user, just the id and name.

```
id = xxxxxxxxxxxxxx;
name = "FB Test";
```

The code for read permissions is as below:

```
FBLoginView *loginView = [[FBLoginView alloc] init];
loginView.center = self.view.center;
loginView.readPermissions = @[@"public_profile", @"email", @"user_friends"];
[loginView setDelegate:self];
[self.view addSubview:loginView];
```

I have also allowed the access to email in facebook for this app.

P.S: I am facing this issue after changing the app name in Xcode. Other apps created using the same facebook account are working fine and fetch all the data requested for in readPermissions.

I can't seem to identify the issue and have tried (almost) everything in this regard.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @DharmeshDhorajiya thanks for the quick reply but i'm afraid this link is for the case when you integrate Facebook using custom UI. I am using FBLoginView which provides an already created FB Login button and handles all calls by itself.

Comment: Most likely your new app is using API v2.4, whereas previously it was a lower API version. API v2.4 limited the number of fields you get returned by default, additional fields now have to specifically asked for in the actual API request you are making. Consult the FB API changelog, it contains details.

Answer (score 0):

Have you changed the bundle ID in Settings -> Basic -> iOS section of the Facebook developer console?

Comment: i did. The bundle id is the same as in the app's info plist. I have also tried creating new app in Facebook Developer portal and added the is and URL types values to my app's plist.

Comment: Try also removing your App from the list of Apps in your Settings as Facebook user and then try to login again, this should trigger the Request permissions window, is e-mail there? By the way this may be a fix itself, just removing and requesting again.

Comment: thanks for the reply but I have also tried your suggestion with no luck.

Comment: so, do you see your app is asking for getting e-mail from facebook?